# struct field name conflict with stl array in GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

```
#include <array>
typedef struct {
  int array;
} tp1;

int main()
{
  std::array<int,8> array1;
  /*int array=0;*/
  /*array ++;*/
  tp1 v1;
  v1.array = 2;
  return 0;
}
```

When struct has field "array" and the code uses std::array, it seems the 2 "array" are conflicted in gdb. I get syntax error in printing v1.array:

```
Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at a2.c:12
12        v1.array = 2;
(gdb) n
13        return 0;
(gdb) p v1.array
A syntax error in expression, near `'.
```

But if I add a local variable "array", it then works fine.

```
(gdb) p array
$1 = 1
(gdb) p v1.array
$2 = 2
```

std::array should be in namespace std, and not related to field name. Not sure why it gets confused.

Any suggestion to print v1.array without the local variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not sure why it gets confused.

This is (was?) surely a bug in GDB.

It does not reproduce when using `GDB 10.0` on `x86_64`, while compiling with `g++ (Debian 9.3.0-8)`:

```
Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.cc:12
12        v1.array = 2;
(gdb) n
13        return 0;
(gdb) p v1.array
$1 = 2
```

Try newer GDB version?